# How to convert object to a string array in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

In my code I store a string array as an object inside a dictionary. Because that dictionary is a `<string,object>` type when I retrieve the value from dict like `dict.item("string")` it gives me only an object (obviously) but I need a string array. How to take it back now ?

I have seen many questions here,
they are like object array to string array, some are same of mine but in java, I need a one line code in Vb.net

edit :
code which stores the string array in to the dictionary 
`string_array[2] = {username, new system.Net.NetworkCredential(string.Empty, password).Password} ; out_Config(row("Name").ToString) = string_array`

Comment: Why not modify your dictionary to take string arrays instead of objects?

Comment: good suggestion. but most of the values are just strings / integers . only in one case when i push the values in to dictionary it is a string array. so i cannot change the whole design just for one special case. also cannot create another variable to hold this pair of values alone. there should be only one dict and that is what <string , object >

Comment: Cast it to string() using `CType(dict("item"), String())`?

Comment: tried , thanks , but getting this  error "unable to cast object of type System.Object[] to System.string[]' !!!

Comment: to be exact this is what i tried 
`CType(in_Config("LogInCredentails"), String()).ToString`

Comment: @seetharaman You should remove the `.ToString` from the end of that.

Comment: that i added to print in the message box to indentify what it prints. if the method worked it should print string[] otherwise object[]. anyways. as i mentioned in the answer below. there was a small mistake while testing the previous answer.  CType did the job !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't modify the dictionary to hold string arrays instead of objects (because it also holds other types) then you can cast the values back to string arrays from objects:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
dict.Add("item", New String() {"1", "2"})

Dim stringArray = CType(dict("item"), String())
```

Comment: this worked , while i was trying to pull the actual code which creates the string array and stores in to the dictionary , i changed string array integer array some where in the middle for testing. now changed back to string array []. after that that typecasting error did not work .

thanks a lot.